# In clojure get "null pointer exception" when doing (first)

Tags: clojure

I'm having trouble reproducing a bug where I get a null pointer exception when I call first on a PersistentArrayMap. If I copy and paste the map and call first it works, but when the map is in a ref it doesn't work. Is this some weird behaviour related to laziness (not my own) ?

Update: I cannot produce an example that fails every time, so I am forcing evaluation of everything now and it seems to work

Comment: Please post some example code. Did you remember to de-ref the ref ? Also, I've run an example and I get IllegalArgumentException instead of NPE.

Comment: I'm trying to reproduce the code. The actual data is in an STM and happens "sometimes", but very hard to reproduce the exact case. I'll post the code as soon as I can

Answer (score 2, accepted):

my general game plan when i suspect that i may have been bitten by the lazy bug is to

put `doseq` around everything until the point of failure starts changing.

ps: pasting a stack trace would help give better answers.

Comment: yeah I've started to force evaluation as I just can't get an isolated example. But thanks, I used doseq and the problem seems to have gone now

Comment: good advice - though I'd add that once you've got it working it's always worth going back through the code to figure out exactly why the problem was happening in the first place. there might be a subtle design problem you need you fix, or at the very least you'll learn how not to fall into the same trap again.....

Comment: and remember to take the doseqs out again.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `first` can never cause an NPE, so the problem is elsewhere. My guess is you tried to deref a ref which was nil:

```
user=> (first @nil)
java.lang.NullPointerException (NO_SOURCE_FILE:0)
```

Comment: The object I call first on returns a set of maps everytime, but maybe it is something related to the ref.. I'll look into that more